# Can a supervision strategy handle a ConnectException?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision

If a remote actor is not available due to power loss Can the supervision strategy handle the situation?

I have coded the example and I have shut down the remote actor system but it seems that the supervision strategy only takes into account Exceptions thrown by the remote actor once reached.

Since I'm not an Akka expert I'd like to know if this is achievable.

Edition:

I have already implemented the subscription to the events that indicates that error in the connection have occurred. I still need to have access to message the sender sent originally so the message do not get lost.

Comment: Hope it will handle, when I wake up. ^) Vote up, keep alive.

Comment: It's all in the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/supervision.html#What_Lifecycle_Monitoring_Means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> DeathWatch for Akka Remote does not (yet) get triggered by connection
>   failures – which means that if the parent node or the network goes
>   down, nobody will get notified. This feature may be added in a future
>   release of Akka Remoting. Akka Cluster, however, has such
>   functionality.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/supervision.html#What_Lifecycle_Monitoring_Means